# TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer when looping through an array of hashed

Tags: ruby, typeerror

I want to iterate through an array of hashed, but I keep getting the TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer error. When I print the values they show up as expected but I get the error regardless.

```
  $portal_automation_version_set = 'PhotonPortalUIAutomation/development'
  $package = 'PhotonUIAutomationTests-1.0'
  $todworker = 'TodWorker/Photon/Prod'
  $one_drive_test_name = 'One drive tests'
  $gdrive_test_name = 'Gdrive storage tests'
  $streaming_test_name = 'Portal streaming tests'
  $beta_sanity_test_name = 'Beta-pdx Sanity'
  $one_drive_test_target = '-Dtestngfile=portal-onedrive-storage-test.xml run-fire-test'
  $gdrive_test_target = '-Dtestngfile=portal-storage-sanity-test.xml run-fire-test'
  $streaming_test_target = '-Dtestngfile=portal-streaming-tests.xml run-fire-test'
  $beta_sanity_test_target  = '-Dtestngfile=portal-smoke-tests.xml run-fire-test'

  $stage_sanity_test_map = {
    Beta:
    [
      {
          sanity_test_name: $one_drive_test_name,
          sanity_test_target: $one_drive_test_name,
          depends_on: nil
      },
      {
          sanity_test_name: $gdrive_test_name,
          sanity_test_target: $gdrive_test_target,
          depends_on: $one_drive_test_name
      },
      {
          sanity_test_name: $streaming_test_name,
          sanity_test_target: $streaming_test_target,
          depends_on: $gdrive_test_name
      },
      {
          sanity_test_name: $beta_sanity_test_name,
          sanity_test_target: $beta_sanity_test_target,
          depends_on: $streaming_test_name
      }
    ]
  }

        $stage_sanity_test_map[:Beta].each do | key |
          puts key[:sanity_test_name]
        end
```

Comment: I don't get any such errors on my machine (running the code you pasted), perhaps it could be ruby version specific (I used 2.4.4)?

Comment: @baseballlover723 I just checked. Ruby version is ruby 2.3.8p459 (2018-10-18 revision 65136) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: I don't get the errors on an online compiler so I'm unsure why I see them when I try locally

Comment: a couple things, try running the code you just posted in IRB, if that doesn't work, then you can be sure that its an issue on your local machine, and you could try things like reinstalling all your gems / reinstalling ruby. If that still doesn't work, I would double check that what you posted is actually what things are when you run your program as a whole, its possible something isn't getting set correct, or something else is interfering with your code